# How to restrict whereHas to ONLY match where condition?

Tags: laravel, postgresql, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I am using Laravel 6.0 and PostgreSQL on Homestead.

This query is returning services which **has at least one** post with `is_assistant = true`:

```
Service::with('posts')
    ->whereHas('posts', function ($q) {
        $q->where('is_assistant', true);
    })
    ->get();
```

Models:

```
class Service extends Model
{
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post');
    }
}

class Post extends Model
{

    protected $casts = [
        'is_assistant' => 'boolean',
    ];

}
```

How to write an Eloquent query that get services which **has ONLY** posts with `is_assistant = true`?

Comment: Can you try with integer instead of boolean in where query. Like this:  $q->where('is_assistant', '=', 1);

Comment: @jureispro I Did it before, didnt work. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can use the `whereDoesntHave` method:

```
Service::with('posts')
    ->whereDoesntHave('posts', function ($q) {
        $q->where('is_assistant', false);
    })
    ->get();
```